# iOS - Parsing filename

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Need to parse filename. Say I have image named pic_1_3_5_4.png. I need something like:

Category1 - 1

Category2 - 3

Category3 - 5

Category4 - 4

I need separate this values. So I can retrieve or only categories (1,2,3,4) or only item numbers (1,3,5,4).

Also I need some code for parsing not only four categories. Maybe I want image like pic_2_4.png. I need parse this to:

Category1 - 2

Category2 - 4

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:

Comment: You should start with ```componentsSeparatedByString``` method of ```NSString```.

Comment: What did you try? Do you want us to write code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific request you can retrieve a list of strings called CategoryX - Y like this :

```
- (NSArray *) listNamesFromFileName:(NSString *) fileName
{

 NSArray *split = [[fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension] componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
//which will result in the following list : "pic","1","2",...
//then build the resulting array

   if(split.count > 1)
   {
     NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
     //starting from 1 to skip "pic"
     for(int i = 1;i < split.count ;i++)
     {
       NSString *value       = [split objectAtIndex:i];
       //Category1 - 3
        NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Category%d - %@",i,value];
       [result addObject:valueString];
      }

     return result;
    }

   return nil;
  }
```

I think this answers your question for every length of fileName

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, its result will be an array with all the components you require. Also you will get pic at 0th index which you can skip or manage accordingly:

```
        NSArray *resultArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
```